# Coords from browser

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to know how to get the x,y coords on click from anywhere in the browser, my script is supposed to record a user if they hit the coord 0, but first I need to know how to get the coords from anywhere in the browser instead of just a certain area. here's my code so far. I've put in a few questions on this subject so far, but to no prevail.

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.button').click(function(e){
        if(e.pageX == 0 || e.pageY ==0){

$.ajax({
    url: 'recorder.php',
});



        }
    }); 
}); 

</script>
```

So I'm guessing to make this work.. I need to replace `$('.button').click` with something, but I do not know with what.

Comment: That code looks correct to me, but you're not doing anything with the result of your ajax call, so you're probably not seeing anything happen.

Comment: You want to listen to the whole document, so `$(document)`.

Comment: @dave, that just leads to some queries so I don't believe I have to do anything with the call do I?

Comment: that depends on what "some queries" means.

Comment: Also as plalx mentioned, you need to use `document` (or maybe `'body'`) to get events for the entire page, rather than just the button class.

Comment: Well anyway, here's a jsFiddle which should help you: http://jsfiddle.net/vZJg9/

Comment: It contains 2 queries, one of which adds the user to the list if they hit coord 0, the other which adds +1 to the previous entry for each time they hit the coord 0. I tried (document) yet it is still not working :/

Answer (score 0):

The DOM event object has following fields:

- clientX: Returns the horizontal coordinate of the mouse pointer, relative to the current window, when an event was triggered
- clientY: Returns the vertical coordinate of the mouse pointer, relative to the current window, when an event was triggered

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_event.asp

Comment: actually jQuery puts `pageX` and `pageY` into its event objects.

Answer (score 0):

You want to trace mouse location on entire `window`.

```
$(window).mousemove(function(event){
    $("#coords").html("X = " + event.pageX + " Y = " + event.pageY);
});
```

with html

```
<div id="coords"></div>
```

With this you'll get mouse position. But it still unclear what you want to next.

**EDIT.** If you want, you change event to `click` instead of mousemove.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/V3yzk/)